# Power BI dynamic column reference with DAX formula

Tags: dynamic, reference, powerbi, dax

I have a `Orders` and `ExchangeRates` tables connected via a `date` key:

[image]

[image]

What I am trying to do is to fetch the correct currency exchange rate from `ExchangeRates`, which are organized in columns, with the column name matching the currency codes from `Orders`.

I'm basically trying to make a dynamic column reference to the `EUR` or `JPY` columns by using the matching `Orders[orderCurrency]` like this:

```
orderExchangeRate = LOOKUPVALUE(ExchangeRates[Orders[orderCurrency]],
ExchangeRates[date],Orders[date])
```

or:

```
orderExchangeRage = SELECTCOLUMNS(ExchangeRates,Orders[orderCurrency], ....)
```

But none of the functions accept a dynamic column reference, they expect the actual name of the column

**How can I dynamically refer to the `EUR` and `JPY` columns based on `Orders[orderCurrency]`? Isn't there something similar to [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) to make a dynamic reference in PowerBI?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such function as INDIRECT in DAX.

You have (at least) two options:

- If it's just EUR and JPY, you could create two formulas and based on the currency switch between them with IF() or SWITCH(). Like: If (Currency = "EUR", LOOKUPVALUE(EUR), LOOKUPVALUE(JPY). Pseudo code, of course.
- Unpivot the EUR and JPY column in the ExchangeRate table. Then you'll have a line for each date and currency, and you can reference it as you like. Especially usefull with more currency combinations. You can Unpivot in the Query Editor, Transformation Tab.

Comment: I went for the unpivot solution as it makes the dataset and formulas simpler